# CSS Classes in Wordpress Navigational Label

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, label

I am trying to highlight two menu items or navigation labels by changing its text color in wordpress theme, Vantage using the CSS classes (enabled through screen options). The class can be seen in the below snip.

[image]

Later, I edit the `style.css` file located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\vantage` and add the following at the end of the file and save the `style.css`

```
   width: auto;
   z-index: 100000;
   /* Above WP toolbar. */
  }

  .sample {
       color: green;
  }
```

After refreshing the homepage, I do not see any change in color for the menu item, "Home". Contrary to this, if I add inline style to the label itself, as shown below, it works.

[image]

Any explanation why the first method (perhaps recommended) doesn't work, while the latter works?

Comment: (1) The class may not be getting added to the element (after you removed the . as Junaid suggested) - check the HTML code in Element Inspector to make sure the class is getting added to the element. *or* (2) there might be another CSS rule overriding yours and cancelling out your style. Check the CSS is the inspector to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter class names only, without the class indicator `.`

So it'll be

[image]

Comment: Tried removing the class indicator (`.`), but it doesn't work.

Comment: If that is so then we come to the point where you disable all your plugins, revert back to default theme and test. If it works, then you need to find out the faulty plugin/theme.